# Resover problema mostrando resultados en un DIV con javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, css, json

tengo el siguiente problema NO RESUELTO y no puedo encontrar el porquè no funciona.
en la siguiente foto muestro los resultados desde una base de datos en unos DIV que son los horarios de los medicos,al hacer click en VER me tendrìa que mostar en los SPAN los horarios DESDE-HASTA y sumar CADA segun lo que se muestra.claramente falta algo que me està volviendo loco
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
paso el codigo en html donde estan mostrados los resultados

```
                        <button type="button" onclick="Obtenerhorariosdesdemedicos()"> 
                        ver</button>
                        <div> <?php echo '<h4> Turno Mañana </h4>'?></div>
                        <div> <h4 id="tmdesde"> <?php echo $lunes['tmdesde']?> </h4></div>
                        <div> <h4 id="tmhasta"> <?php echo $lunes['tmhasta']?> </h4></div>
                        <div> <?php echo '<h4> Turno Tarde </h4>'?></div>
                        <div> <h4 id="ttdesde"> <?php echo $lunes['ttdesde']?> </h4></div>
                        <div> <h4 id="tthasta"> <?php echo $lunes['tthasta']?> </h4></div>
                        <div> <?php echo '<h4> Turnos cada </h4>'?></div>
                        <div> <h4 id="cada"> <?php echo $lunes['cada']?> </h2></div>

                        
                        <span id="resultados-1" class="input-group-text">8:00 a.m</span>
                        <span id="resultados-2" class="input-group-text">8:15 a.m</span>
                        <span id="resultados-3" class="input-group-text">8:30 a.m</span>
                        <span id="resultados-4" class="input-group-text">8:45 a.m</span>
                        <span id="resultados-5" class="input-group-text">9:00 a.m</span>
```

en el evento onclick està el problema que no me muestra los horarios en los SPAN

```
                       function Obtenerhorariosdesdemedicos() {
                         /*Referencia al div contenedor general*/
                        mDiv = document.getElementById('resultados' + n);
                        /*variables que contienen los horarios*/
                        /*turno mañana*/
                        mtminicio = document.getElementById('tmdesde')
                        mtmfin = document.getElementById('tmhasta')
                       /*turno tarde*/
                       ttminicio = document.getElementById('ttdesde')
                       ttmfin = document.getElementById('tthasta')
                       /*cada tantos minutos de atencion*/
                       mcada = document.getElementById('cada')
                       /*Fragmento para ir agregando cada elemento*/
                       var mFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();


                        const Horario = {
                             dia: {
                               inicio: mtminicio,
                               fin: mtmfin
                             },
                             tarde: {
                               inicio: ttminicio,
                               fin: ttmfin
                              },
                             cada: mcada,
                              };
                              var now = new Date();
                              var inicial = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(),
                              now.getDay(), Horario.dia.inicio, 0, 0, 0);
                              var final = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), 
                              now.getDay(),
                              Horario.dia.fin, 0, 0, 0);
                              /*Variable para identificar cada id de los p*/
                              var i = 1;
                              for (var f = inicial; f <= final; f.setMinutes(f.getMinutes() +
                              Horario.cada)) {
                              let hora = ("0" + String(f.getHours())).slice(-2); //slice para 
                              dar formato de 2 digitos
                              let minutos = ("0" + String(f.getMinutes())).slice(-2);
                              /*Creamos un elemento p*/
                              var mP = document.createElement("p");
                              /*Establecemos su id con el valor de i y aumentamos i en 1*/
                              mP.setAttribute("id", `p${i++}`);
                              //console.log(mP);
                              /*Le agregamos el contenido de forma segura*/
                              mP.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`${hora}:${minutos}`));
                              /*Lo agregamos al fragmento*/
                              mFragment.appendChild(mP);
                               //console.log(hora + ":" + minutos);
                                }
                                 /*Finalmente, agregamos el fragmento al div contenedor*/
                                 var elementos = document.getElementById('resultados' + n);
                                 for(i = 0; i <= elementos.id; i++) {
                                 if(elementos[i].id != ('resultados-' + n)) {
                                 mDiv.appendChild(mFragment);
                                }
                               }
                              }
```

gracias por su paciencia y predisposicion.

Comment: Por favor, describe además lo que aparece en la imagen. [No todos pueden ver las imágenes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976).

Comment: hola donde tenes definida la variable "n"? la usas en el codigo pero no veo donde esta declarada

Comment: Cuando haces `mtminicio = document.getElementById('tmdesde')` estás asignando a `mtminicio` el objeto en sí, con lo que cuando generas la propiedad `inicio` de `Horario.dia` le asigna el objeto y no el valor. Lo mismo con el resto de elementos. Me imagino que querrás asignarle su contenido, ¿no? Siendo un h4 sería algo como `document.getElementById('tmdesde').innerHTML`, pero teniendo en cuenta espacios en blanco y muchas cosas peligrosas. Yo personalmente tal vez lo haría con campos `input`. Pero bueno... ese no es el tema

Comment: ahh pense que se veia la imagen mil disculpas....la imagen dice que tengo 5 resultados de horarios obtenidos desde una base de datos,son turno mañana INICIO (ID="tmdesde") ,HASTA(ID="tmhasta), Turno tarde INICIO(ID="ttdesde"), HASTA(ID="tthasta") y CADA(ID="cada") y quisiera que en los SPAN me aparezcan correlativos los horarios descriptos cada tantos minutos sumandolos. no se si estoy siendo claro en las preguntas.gracias